# GridLayout Arrangement

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qgridlayout

Following is my **main.qml**:

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ListModel {
        id: _listModel
        ListElement {
            textData: "E1"
            isEnabled: false
        }
        ListElement {
            textData: "E2"
            isEnabled: false
        }
        ListElement {
            textData: "E3"
            isEnabled: false
        }
        ListElement {
            textData: "E4"
            isEnabled: false
        }
        ListElement {
            textData: "E5"
            isEnabled: false
        }
        ListElement {
            textData: "E6"
            isEnabled: false
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: _listview
        model: _listModel
        width: 100
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            anchors.right: parent.right
            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                if (isEnabled)
                    visibleRecs++;
            }

            RowLayout {
                Text {
                    id: itemText
                    text: qsTr(textData)
                }
                CheckBox {
                    height: 30
                    width: height
                    checked: isEnabled
                    onCheckedChanged: {
                        isEnabled = checked
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        id: _scrollView
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        clip: true
        GridLayout {
            id: _gridLayout
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            columnSpacing: 10
            rowSpacing: 10
            columns: 2

            Repeater {
                model: _listModel
                Loader {
                    id: _loader
                    sourceComponent: isEnabled ? _recComponent : null
                    onLoaded: {
                        item.text = textData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    Component {
        id: _recComponent
        Rectangle {
            property alias text : _txt.text
            id: _rec
            width: 100
            height: 50
            radius: 5
            color: "yellow"
            Text {
                id: _txt
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code creates following (when all check boxes are ticked): 
**When all checkboxes are ticked:** 
[image] 
**When checkbox E3 is unchecked:** 
[image]

I want the items to be rearranged in the gridlayout if any of the item goes invisible. 
E.g. in the above case when E3 is unchecked, I want my view to be something like this: 
[image]

Please let me know, if it is possible to achieve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: thumbsup for very complete question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you still instantiate the `Loader`, you just set the `sourceComponent` to `null`. You have to make the item invisible to not use space in the `GridLayout` (or put width/height to 0)

```
ScrollView {
    id: _scrollView
    width: parent.width / 2
    height: parent.height
    clip: true
    GridLayout {
        id: _gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        columnSpacing: 10
        rowSpacing: 10
        columns: 2

        Repeater {
            model: _listModel
            Loader {
                id: _loader
                visible: isEnabled
                sourceComponent: isEnabled ? _recComponent : null
                onLoaded: {
                    item.text = textData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```