# Show hide component in a repeater

Tags: qt, qml, repeater, property-binding

I've some instances of the following that I'm displaying in a repeater through a loaded component. And I'm trying to control the **visibility** of the repeated component:

```
property var modes : [new modeClass("Mode 1", "mode1", noteC1)];

function modeClass(name, representation, note) {
    var active = true;
    this.name = name;
    this.representation = representation;
    this.note = note;
    this.activated = true;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "activated", {
        get : function () {
            return active;
        },
        set : function (newActive) {
            active = newActive;
            if (!active)
                note.selected = false;
            this.dummy = active;
            console.log(name, this.dummy);
        },
        enumerable : true
    });

    this.dummy = active;
}
```

And the repeater:

```
// Repeater pour les notes des modes
Repeater {
    id : repModes
    model : modes 
    //delegate : holeComponent - via Loader, to specify the "note" to display
    Loader {
        id : loaderModes
        Binding {
            target : loaderModes.item
            property : "note"
            value : modes[model.index].note
        }
        Binding {
            target : loaderModes.item
            property : "visible"
            value : modes[model.index].activated
        }
        sourceComponent : holeComponent
    }
}
```

I'm controlling the `activated` property of the modeClass instance through some checkbox.

I don't manage to have the property-binding for the visibility to work.
It works only a the **instantiation** of the component  and does not react on the property changes.

I've tried several ways to do the binding:

#### Alternative 1

With the property with the getter and setter

```
        Binding {
            target : loaderModes.item
            property : "visible"
            value : modes[model.index].activated
        }
```

#### Alternative 2

With "direct" property (no getter, no setter)

```
        Binding {
            target : loaderModes.item
            property : "visible"
            value : modes[model.index].dummy
        }
```

#### Alternative 3

With a "bottom-up" approach

```
    Loader {
        id : loaderModes
        ...
        property bool showhide: modes[model.index].activated
        //property bool showhide: modes[model.index].dummy
        sourceComponent : holeComponent
    }
```

and in the component:

```
Component {
    id : holeComponent

    Image {
        id : img
        property var note
        visible : showhide
```

#### Alternative 4

Work at the model level:

```
Repeater {
    id : repModes
    model : modes.filter(function(m) { return m.activated; })
    //model : modes.filter(function(m) { return m.dummy; })
```

None of these works. The visibility of the *holeComponent*s remains all the time the one at instantiation.

Any other approach ?

======================
Edit 27/10: a KISS version:

```
ColumnLayout {
    id : layConfig

    Repeater {
        model : modes
        delegate : CheckBox {
            id : chkConfig
            property var __mode : modes[model.index]
            Layout.alignment : Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.QtAlignBottom
            text : __mode.name + (__mode.activated ? "++" : "--")
            checked : __mode.activated;
            onClicked : {
                console.log("onClik",__mode.name,modelData.name);
                __mode.activated = !__mode.activated;
                console.log("mode.activated ==> ",__mode.activated);
                console.log("modelData.activated ==> ",modelData.activated);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I expect that when click the checkbox, the checkbox text is changed automaticaly by property-binding. IT DOES NOT. I guess it might be related to the `property var __mode : modes[model.index]`. I should use instead `modelData`. But with `modelData` I don't have access to updated underlying object properties. And so it doesn't work neither.

Log output:

```
Debug: onClik Mode 1 Mode 1
Debug: mode.activated ==>  **true**
Debug: modelData.activated ==>  **false**

Debug: onClik Mode 1 Mode 1
Debug: mode.activated ==>  false
Debug: modelData.activated ==>  false
```

Comment: Why don't you define a property in some [common](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html) QML way but using `Object.defineProperty`? What a component do you want to instantiate in the Repeater? anyway I see that [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is not your favorite :-)

Comment: Please try to bind to the `visible` property of the `Loader`, like my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261836/gridlayout-arrangement/64262798#64262798

Comment: Amfasis it doesn't work. I guess the problem is somewhere else. Please look at my smaller example. The problem seems linked to accessing the objects in the model. @foibis I confess, I come from a strongly-typed world (java) and I can't get rid of my pure OO habits. What would you suggest to get it more KISS ?

Comment: Am I facing some shortcomings of the QML optimization that stops the property-binding after some level of deepness ?

Comment: I suggest that you set up a separate data structure that contains uuids and modes / properties, **var data = [{uuid: 1234, mode: xyz}, {uuid:2382, mode: abc}]**.   Then you can have the delegate query the data or pass the correct data to the delegate by the **connect**' feature upon instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this hack on internet and have applied it to my case with success :

[QML trick: force re-evaluation of a property binding](http://www.mardy.it/blog/2016/11/qml-trick-force-re-evaluation-of.html)

The issue lays in the fact, that qml does only re-evaluate the `modelData` upon re-evaluation of the `model` what it does only when there is an **obvious change** in the model. So a change in an underlying object of the model is not detected. And this is what I was trying to achieve.

So the hack is basically:

And the repeater:

```
// Repeater pour les notes des modes
Repeater {
    id : repModes
    model : ready?getActivatedModes():[] // awful hack 
    //delegate : holeComponent - via Loader, to specify the "note" to display
    Loader {
        id : loaderModes
        Binding {
            target : loaderModes.item
            property : "note"
            value : modes[model.index].note
        sourceComponent : holeComponent
    }
}
```

And the repeater for the controlling checkboxes :

```
Repeater {
    model : __config 
    delegate : CheckBox {
        id : chkConfig
        property var __mode : __config[model.index]
        Layout.alignment : Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.QtAlignBottom
        text : __mode.name
        checked : __mode.activated // init only
        onClicked : {
            __mode.activated = !__mode.activated;
            ready= false; // awful trick to force the refresh
            ready= true;
        }
    }
}
```

The `ready=false; ready=true;` is, for qml, an **obvious change** in the model, so qml re-evaluates the model and repaints everything correctly.